# Stopping movement of sprite if it's same position as another sprite

Tags: javascript, sprite, collision-detection

I am trying to make a very short game, where a ball goes inside a goal and then they both disappear. How do I do that? I am fairly new to Javascript. Problem is at comment //ball in goal(the "background("blue")" is a placeholder for what I am actually trying to do).

```
goal.setAnimation("goal for design.png_1");
goal.scale = 0.75;
goal.rotation = 5;

var ball = createSprite(40, randomNumber(25, 360));
ball.setAnimation("animation_1");


function draw() {
  background("white");
  // BALL MOVING CODE
  if (keyDown ("right")) {
    ball.x = ball.x + 5;
  }
  if (keyDown ("down")) {
    ball.y = ball.y + 5;
  }
  if (keyDown ("up")) {
    ball.y = ball.y - 5;
  }
  if (keyDown ("left")) {
    ball.x = ball.x - 5;
  }

  // ball in goal
  if ((ball.x && ball.y) == (goal.x && goal.y)) {
    background("blue");
  }

  drawSprites();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
if ((ball.x && ball.y) == (goal.x && goal.y)) {
  //...
}
```

assuming that you want to check whether the coordinates of your `ball` and `goal` are the same, the expression is incorrect.

Let's see how this expression is evaluated:

1. First, `(ball.x && ball.y)` is evaluated to whatever `ball.y` is, unless `ball.x` is falsy. That is, `(-5 && 10)` -> `10` and `(0 && 10)` -> `0`.
2. Next, `(goal.x && goal.y)` is evaluated in the same manner as above.
3. Finally, the equality operator `==` does the comparison of the 1. and 2.

This logic obviously won't work as expected in most of the cases.

For example, when `ball` is `{x: 1, y: 10}` and `goal` is `{x: 20, y: 10}`:

`(1 && 10) == (20 && 10)` -> `(10) == (10)` -> `true`

Certainly not the result you'd want.

---

What you need to do is compare the coordinates one by one and combine the results with the logical AND:

```
if ((ball.x === goal.x) && (ball.y === goal.y)) {
  //...
}
```